# Flutter: How to move the modelBottomSheet up with the keyboard?

Tags: flutter

This is the screenshot of the screen. When the floatingActionButton is clicked, I'm presenting modekBottomSheet. The modelBottomSheet has 4 TextFields and 1 RaisedButton. I want the textField and raised button go up along with the keyboard. The RaisedButton bottom should be the top of the keyboard.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return _showModelBottomSheetContent(context);
        },
      );
    },
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    child: Icon(
      Icons.add,
      size: 30,
    ),
  ),


Container _showModelBottomSheetContent(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  color: Color(0xFF737373),
  height: 440,
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 12, right: 12, bottom: 20),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          "Add Customer",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        ),
        TextField(
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Customer Name",
            fillColor: Colors.white54,
            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              borderSide: new BorderSide(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Mobile No",
            fillColor: Colors.white54,
            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              borderSide: new BorderSide(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Altername mobile no.",
            fillColor: Colors.white54,
            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              borderSide: new BorderSide(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        TextField(
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Address",
            fillColor: Colors.white54,
            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              borderSide: new BorderSide(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text(
            'ADD',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
          ),
          onPressed: handleAddCustomer,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        )
      ],
    ),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: const Radius.circular(12),
        topRight: const Radius.circular(12),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18564

Comment: I tried setting bottom padding as  MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom but it didn't worked

Comment: try to read all messages in this conversation

Comment: Tried all but nothing worked